# x64dbg execute till next call OR return

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, debuggers, x64dbg

I am using x64dbg and I want to know if there's any way to run the code till next Call statement?

I know there is an "Execute till return" option,

but I want to execute till next call statement or next CMP or any other statements.

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, So I've found a way to Execute till Call,

Open "Trace Over" (CTRL+ALT+F8) and write this break condition:


dis.iscall(EIP)

What that does is checking if the current statement is a CALL, and if that's true it will break, other wise the code will keep executing.

Comment: But Is there a way to bind this to a hotkey or something, or make the trace over remember the condition instead of me setting this condition each click?

Comment: The condition is saved in the edit box, just press arrow up. There is also a way to bind a command to a hotkey. TraceOverConditional “dis.iscall(eip)” should work

Comment: @mrexodia Developer of x64dbg is here :O
Thank you so much for the great debugger and awesome support <3

Please write this in an answer instead of comment so I can mark it <3
BTW I can't figure out how to bind TraceOverConditional into a hotkey,
I can use it in the command editbox in the bottom like: "TraceOverConditional dis.iscall(EIP) || dis.isret(EIP)" which is a lot better.
Thanks so much. <3